# Firebase push notification not showing on ios10

Tags: xcode, firebase, ios10, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm using Xcode 7 and developing an app with push notification. However, I found out that all push notifications cannot be shown on iOS 10 devices. Is there any solution to fix it?

P.S. push notification is working fine on iOS 9.

Comment: hey @ray did you find a solution for this question? i'm also searching for a solution..

Comment: @GaneshKumar i cannot find a solution so updated to xcode 8 and rewrite it .

Comment: i have also updated the code to swift 3. but the push notifications are not received in my phone. can you help me with this?

Comment: @GaneshKumar I used Google Firebase service. It provides simply information on how to setup push notification. Check out this:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to Xcode 8 is compulsory~ Otherwise, push notification would not work on iOS 10

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently having the same issue here.

I believe the problem could be the following:

The Firebase iOS 10 implementation uses the following pre-compiler macro:

`#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0`

Well, Xcode 7 works with the iOS 9 SDK so the `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED`'s value is `__IPHONE_9_3` which is lower then the `__IPHONE_10_0`'s value.

Basically when you build the project with Xcode 7, the iOS 10 Firebase implementation won't be compiled into the application.. Moreover Xcode 7 cannot recognise the `UserNotifications` framework..

I tried to copy the iOS 10 SDK into Xcode 7's directory but it was a bad idea